# How to use array destructuring and assign to an object property in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

This code:

```
const eat = { when: 'now' }
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

eat.fruit = fruits[1] // orange
```

I can use array destructuring like this:

```
const [, selectedFruit] = fruits

eat.fruit = selectedFruit
```

But can I make a one-liner out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use that

```
[, eat.fruit] = fruits // remove const
console.log(eat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use merging here like:

```js
let eat = { when: 'now' }
const fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

eat = {...eat, fruit: fruits[1]}
console.log( eat )
```

Comment: Although works but I won't recommend this. Compromising efficiency just to get one liner solution is not good idea, at least IMHO. Instead, one can create a new property and assign it the selected value by finding in the same statement e.g `eat.fruit = fruits.indexOf()` or something similar.